# SSH into staging machine from docker instance using Bitbucket Pipelines

Tags: authentication, ssh, docker, public-key, bitbucket-pipelines

Using the new Bitbucket Pipelines feature, how can I SSH into my staging box from the docker container it spins up?

The last step in my pipeline is an `.sh` file that deploys the necessary code on staging, however because my staging box uses public key authentication and doesn't know about the docker container, the SSH connection is being denied.

Anyway of getting around this without using password authentication over SSH (which is causing me issues as well by constantly choosing to authenticate over public key instead.)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bitbucket pipelines can use a Docker image you've created, that has the ssh client setup to run during your builds, as long as it's hosted on a publicly accessible container registry.

#### Create a Docker image.

[Create a Docker image](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockerimages/) with your ssh key available somewhere. The image also needs to have the [host key for your environment(s) saved](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94275/22470) under the user the container will run as. This is normally the `root` user but may be different if you have a `USER` command in your `Dockerfile`.

You could copy an already populated `known-hosts` file in or configure the file dynamically at image build time with:

```
RUN ssh-keyscan your.staging-host.com
```

#### Publish the image

Publish your image to a publicly accessible, but **private** registry. You can [host your own](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/) or use a service like [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/billing-plans/).

#### Configure Pipelines

[Configure pipelines to build with your docker image](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-docker-images-as-build-environments-in-bitbucket-pipelines-792298897.html).

If you use Docker Hub

```
image:
  name: account-name/java:8u66
  username: $USERNAME
  password: $PASSWORD
  email: $EMAIL
```

Or Your own external registry

```
  name: docker.your-company-name.com/account-name/java:8u66
```

#### Restrict access on your hosts

You don't want to have ssh keys to access your hosts flying around the world so I would also restrict access for these deploy ssh keys to [only run your deploy commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110939/22470).

The `authorized_keys` file on your staging host:

```
command="/path/to/your/deploy-script",no-agent-forwarding,no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding ssh-dss AAAAC8ghi9ldw== deploy@bitbucket
```

Unfortunately bitbucket [don't publish an IP list to restrict access to](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/12846/document-pipeline-agent-ips-for-network)   as they use shared infrastructure for pipelines. If they happen to be running on AWS then Amazon do [publish IP lists](https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json).

```
from="10.5.0.1",command="",no-... etc
```

Also remember to date them an expire them from time to time. I know ssh keys don't enforce dates but it's a good idea to do it anyway.

Comment: Hi @Matt, how secure is public accessible but in private registry?

Comment: @JamesLin As secure as any other service you host on external infrastructure, which is pretty much everything these days.  Do you trust the company hosting the registry to keep it secure?

Comment: The reason I am asking is, when it's public accessible, but the registry is private, if someone knows the registry name, they can download that?

Comment: A publicly hosted private registry should always require [authentication for access](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#/restricting-access).

Answer (score 2):

You can now setup SSH keys under pipeline settings so that you do not need to have a private docker image just to store ssh keys.  It is also extracted from your source code so you don't have it in your repo as well.

Under

```
Settings -> Pipelines -> SSH keys
```

You can either provide a key pair or generate a new one.  The private key will be put in the docker container at `~/.ssh/config` and provide you a public key you can put in your host to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.  The page also requires an ip or name to setup the fingerprint for known hosts when running on docker as well.

Also, Bitbucket has provided IP addresses you can white list if necessary for the docker containers being spun up.  They are [currently](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/what-are-the-bitbucket-cloud-ip-addresses-i-should-use-to-configure-my-corporate-firewall-343343385.html):

- 34.236.25.177/32
- 34.232.25.90/32
- 52.203.14.55/32
- 52.202.195.162/32
- 52.204.96.37/32
- 52.54.90.98/32
- 34.199.54.113/32
- 34.232.119.183/32
- 35.171.175.212/32